# Difference between pytorch torchvision and conda-forge torchvision

Tags: python, pytorch, version-control, anaconda, torchvision

I tried to install the latest version of torchvision (`v0.13.0`) on my anaconda3 environment (python 3.9.12) on mac, with `conda install -c pytorch torchvision` as shown [here](https://anaconda.org/pytorch/torchvision):

[image]

but I got `torchvision == v.0.2.2` instead.

There is a `conda-forge` version of torchvision (`v.0.12.0`) that I found [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/torchvision) and I can get with `conda install -c conda-forge torchvision`, but I'm not sure the difference between them and which one I should use.

My questions are:

- What are the difference between `pytorch torchvision` and `conda-forge torchvision`?
- How to choose which one to use?
- Is there a way to install `v0.13.0`? (Is there a command to get `v0.13.0`?)

Thank you,